# Javascript file not loading ,when enabling Richtextbox

Tags: javascript

i have written code for TinyMCE richtextbox for content management in my blog. But i am getting an error while loading this

> ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)

But when i view the page source code for richtextbox is binded in my source like this

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

    (function(){ 

        tinyMCE.init({

            // General options
            mode: "exact",
            elements: "DisplayContent",
            theme: "advanced",
            height: "500",
            width: "790",
            verify_html : false,
      plugins : "pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,wordcount,advlist,autosave",

      // Theme options
      theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
      theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
      theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
      theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak,restoredraft,codehighlighting,netadvimage",
      theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
      theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
      theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
      theme_advanced_resizing : false,

      // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
      //content_css : "css/content.css",
            content_css : "/Scripts/tinymce/css/content.css",
            convert_urls : false,

      // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
      template_external_list_url : "lists/template_list.js",
      external_link_list_url : "lists/link_list.js",
      external_image_list_url : "lists/image_list.js",
      media_external_list_url : "lists/media_list.js",

     });

    })();

</script>
```

```html
<textarea Length="0" cols="20" id="DisplayContent" name="DisplayContent" rows="2">
</textarea>
```

What can i do for view the richtextbox?

Comment: Seems like permission issue for the js files. Please check  does all js files have appropriate persmissions.

Comment: how can i set permissions in js files @Sagar

Comment: As posted above, check file/folder permissions and do you have any other errors in the console? Maybe try open the js files to ensure you can access them by visiting the direct path  `www.yourdomain.com/lists/template_list.js` Are you trying to run this live on a server or locally? If live on a server would it be possible for you to give a link to the problem in question. Thank you.

Comment: no, we can't directly open the js files.Running now in locally @NewToJS

Comment: Possible for you to create a copy of your project and `zip` the folder so I can download it and run/test this locally to try recreate your problem or maybe give me a link to the TinyMCE you are using?

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/rich-text-box-in-Asp-Net-mvc/ i take it from this link @NewToJS

Comment: So you are using `.ASP`? If so then I recommend you tag `.asp` to your question. I don't see any relation to the link source code with what you have provided. The link you have posted doesn't contain any `javascript`